# How to design my site page in sharepoint, only want to use .net

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, asp.net, .net

I know asp .net but new at sharepoint.But i still setup sharepoint farm solution at azure it is working now i want to developer a site i am strting it with emptySP Project at .Net.

step1: i take one ApplicationPage say(ApplicationPage1)
step2: Make registration form at inside place holder main.
step3 :run

All thing is working but it's still look like sharepoint page not my page.
I want to remove the master page of share point and want to runt a basic aspx page like we use in .net . 
So,plese tell me if there is any solution.

ContentPlaceholder's are also not work,like if i use site Name and set it's value to "MySite", but it still show SHAREPOINT. i paste Image.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to do that

- Create a blank custom master page and attach it to your page.
- Or just remove `DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>` from     `<%@Page tag%>`

**PageTag**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="yourpage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Something.Layouts.namespace" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>
```

- Now replace all `Placeholders` tags with normal `<HTML>,<Head>,<Body>,<form id="form1" runat="server">` tags as the structure of normal forntcode aspx page.

**The application page should look like**

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ApplicationPage1.aspx.cs" Inherits="EPMCP.Layouts.EPMCP.ApplicationPage1"  %>

    <html><head></head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Replace my button with your front code
**Output**

[image]

Comment: option of adding master page is not present in it and and after removing this "DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" ,it bringup a runtime error

Comment: are you removed content place holders after delete DynamicMasterPageFile as i mentioned above and replace it with the mentioned tags

Comment: i am pretty sure it's should worked, i just tried it again now , just make sure your have removed all content placholders and replace it with html structure like this <html><head></head><body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
    </body></html>